# Usage of articles with phrases

Tags: grammar, word-usage, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

No article is used before a noun used in phrases as: to leave home, to send word, to catch fire, etc etc. Examples: He sent me word to see him. He left home. Here is my question: why do not these phrases take articles like 1. He sent me a/the word to see him. 2. He left a/the home.

Comment: See this thread on ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/244622/omission-of-articles-in-phrases/244628#244628

Comment: All of those clauses would actually mean something different with the article...

Comment: @Kate Bunting I have already seen that answer but  I am asking pattern like : verb+ noun(object). Examples: to catch fire, to give ear, to take offense, to give battle, to set foot etc.. So the answer said nouns of all these phrases are uncountable?

Comment: @Rattler I have already mentioned "No article is used before a noun used in phrases". You are saying with the articles?

Comment: "to leave _the_ home." means one was in a care facility. "to send _the_ word." could be a single word, or even scripture. etc.

Comment: These are simply set expressions in English,  as the other thread explains. The only reason is 'that's how we say it'. _Home_ is one's  own place of residence - _a home_ is a residential institution. To _send word_  is to send a message.